# Is there a keyboard shortcut to get to the Desktop on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu

I'm sure there's a keyboard shortcut to get to the Desktop on Ubuntu but all I can find is the little icon in the lower right of the taskbar that you have to click on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the keyboard shortcut would be <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>